# Why do the references not appear here?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I have made a separate references.bib file as follow and then added in the main.tex but it doesn't appear. 
Any idea how to fix this?

This is my `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
This is an example.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

and this is the `references.bib` which is put in the same folder.

```
@article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
@inproceedings{FosterEtAl:2003,
  author = {George Foster and Simona Gandrabur and Philippe Langlais and Pierre
    Plamondon and Graham Russell and Michel Simard},
  title = {Statistical Machine Translation: Rapid Development with Limited Resources},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of {MT Summit IX}},
  year = {2003},
  pages = {110--119},
  address = {New Orleans, USA},
}
@phdthesis{Alsolami:2012,
    title    = {An examination of keystroke dynamics
                for continuous user authentication},
    school   = {Queensland University of Technology},
    author   = {Eesa Alsolami},
    year     = {2012}
}
```

However, this is the result when I complile `main.tex`. The reference doesn't appear:

[image]

Comment: you need to `\cite` something (or `\cite{*}`) and use bibtex to generate a bibliography. LaTeX never reads the `.bib` file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want to make a list of reference articles at the end of the paper.  How can I do that?

Comment: Add `\nocite{*}` before `\bibliography` command

Comment: @koleygr nice bro, I was manually cite singe one and then deleted to use the method.

Comment: Welcome @emnha ... Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\begin{document}
This is an example.
\cite{knuth:1984,FosterEtAl:2003,Alsolami:2012}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is recommended that you use `cite` package instead of `natbib` package. There are the following descriptions in the sample file [bare_jrnl.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bare_jrnl.tex) for reference.

```latex
% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
%
%\usepackage{cite}
% cite.sty was written by Donald Arseneau
% V1.6 and later of IEEEtran pre-defines the format of the cite.sty package
% \cite{} output to follow that of the IEEE. Loading the cite package will
% result in citation numbers being automatically sorted and properly
% "compressed/ranged". e.g., [1], [9], [2], [7], [5], [6] without using
% cite.sty will become [1], [2], [5]--[7], [9] using cite.sty. cite.sty's
% \cite will automatically add leading space, if needed. Use cite.sty's
% noadjust option (cite.sty V3.8 and later) if you want to turn this off
% such as if a citation ever needs to be enclosed in parenthesis.
% cite.sty is already installed on most LaTeX systems. Be sure and use
% version 5.0 (2009-03-20) and later if using hyperref.sty.
% The latest version can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite
% The documentation is contained in the cite.sty file itself.
```